# Internet connection between mobile and PC using sockets

Tags: c#, android, sockets, xamarin

I've tried to establish internet connection between mobile (client) and PC (server) using sockets in C#. It's just sending text string, nothing big but it doesn't work. Same client code works between PCs. Any tips or advises how I can achieve it?

Client:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ClientPhone
{
    [Activity(Label = "ClientPhone", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {       
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            button.Click += delegate { Connect(); };
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            TextView stateTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.stateTextView);
            stateTextView.Text = "Clicked";
            try
            {
                clientSocket.Connect("MyIp", 5000);

                stateTextView.Text = "Connected";
                clientSocket.Send(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world phone"));
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                stateTextView.Text = "Couldn't connect";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            byte[] recieveBuffor = new byte[256];
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("MyIp"),5000));
            serverSocket.Listen(1);
            Socket client = serverSocket.Accept();
            client.Receive(recieveBuffor);
            Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recieveBuffor));
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I marked *Internet* in the Android manifest properties. I also tried to connect when the phone was on a mobile internet and using WiFi broadcasting by my PC (when they are in local). When I debug the phone app it stops at `clientSocket.Connect("MyIp", 5000)` and then after few seconds it throws a socket exception.

Comment: What is "MyIp"?

Comment: there are tools you can use for Android to ping an IP - I'd first rule out connectivity and firewall issues.  And when you say it "throws a socket exception" which SPECIFIC exception is that?

Comment: Are you getting Network on Main thread exception?  You need to code your networking calls onto a background thread.

Comment: SushiHangover "MyIP" is ip in format xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Jason it is Connection timed out
So, it could be more of firewall issue on my PC where server is actvie? I will try to fix it.

Comment: a timeout is a network connectivity issue.  Keep in mind that if your phone is on mobile internet it is not going to be able to reach your local PC unless you have some sort of port forwarding setup.

Comment: Oh, ok. So i guess i have another thing to learn. Thanks.

Comment: If the PC and mobile are in the same WiFi network, protocols such as Bonjour can help. If they are internet apart, a common approach would be use a cloud service as mediator.